# Comic strip in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am creating figures using Stykz.
Every frame (should have customisable resolution) consists of

1. stick figure
2. 2 or more text boxes
3. Frame[image] outline (will be best if looks handdrawn)

I want to fit exactly 4 such frames on next to each other one page of the pdf, and next 4 on next page and so on...

something like this
[image]

How can I do this in TeX?

Comment: You can use `beamer` with simple `includegraphics` with a clean theme.

Comment: Please add a link to Stykz. In other words, I want to be sure, whether you meant [Stykz](http://www.stykz.net/). And a suggestion: Be so kind and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

When you have your four boxes, you can simply put them into a tabular:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
(first box) & (second box) & (third box) & (fourth box)
\end{tabular}
```